# DolphinDB function to obtain the maximum consecutive positive sum in a sliding window?

Tags: dolphindb

For example

```
v =  10 -1 0 0 1 2 3 1 0 0 -1 -1
maxPositiveStreak(iif(v>0, 1, 0))
```

I used function `maxPositiveStreak` to return the maximum value of of the sum of consecutive positive elements of v in DolphinDB.

What function can I use if I’d like to obtain the maximum consecutive positive sum in a sliding window of size 4?

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `moving` with `maxPositiveStreak` in DolphinDB:

```
v = 10 -1 0 0 1 2 3 1 0 0 -1 -1
n=4
moving(maxPositiveStreak,iif(v>0, 1, 0), n)
```